# Comparing two tables columns

Tags: mysql

**O/p from this Report- Subject Report
    /*Displays all the science subject  from report Subject*/**

```
SELECT `Contact Email Address`,
       `Studentname`,
       `TypeofSubjectLine`
FROM   `Subject`
WHERE  `TypeofSubjectLine`IN ('Science, Maths')
```

**Student Report**

```
SELECT `studentreport`.`Contact Email Address`,
       CASE WHEN `subject`.`Contact Email Address` IS NOT NULL THEN 'new registration' 
       ELSE 'No New Registration' END AS NewRegistraion
FROM   `subject` LEFT JOIN `studentreport` 
ON `subject`.`Contact Email Address`=`studentreport`.`Contact Email Address`
```

Student email address which exists in Report- studentreport,  only  map those students who has subjects in Science and Maths ONLY (subject report). If the students subject is Science & Maths then their email address match and they are -"not new registration", if their email address do not match then they are "new registration"
   Please tell me what is wrong in my query ?

Comment: What was wrong with your query? Are there any error message? Or the output result wasn't correct?

Comment: The second query doesn't have `WHERE TypeofSubjectLine in ('Science', 'Maths')`.

Comment: You shouldn't have the comma inside the string. `'Science, Maths'` should be `'Science', 'Maths'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `studentreport`.`Contact Email Address`,
       CASE WHEN `subject`.`Contact Email Address` IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'new registration' 
       ELSE 'No New Registration' END AS NewRegistraion
FROM   `subject` LEFT JOIN `studentreport` 
    ON `subject`.`Contact Email Address`=`studentreport`.`Contact Email Address`
WHERE  `TypeofSubjectLine`IN ('Science', 'Maths')
```